# Windows 10 - find out where sound is coming from

Tags: windows-10

My cat pressed on a function key on my keyboard and now a playlist or song plays somewhere in the background. I don't know how to stop it, there is no suspicious task in the task manager or in the tray.

How can I figure out where the sound is coming from?

Comment: Restarting from scratch should stop it - don't use shut-down, as by default this will hibernate, then carry on with all the previously running applications.

Comment: A simple restart will probably stop it.

Comment: Yes I know that a restart stops it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Right click on volume icon in systray, select mixer and you can see all applications that are using sound devices, can see VU bars showing sound levels, mute each one separately to see which application is doing the sound etc.

Comment: For people with foreign translations: the mixer is the second item in the context menu.

Answer (score 2):

If you run Windows 10 v1809 or higher and you have the Game bar installed (only the N version without the Media Tool Pack does not have it), then you can press Win+G to open the overlay.

If you get a window that asks with what program to open, Select Windows Store and it will allow you to install the App.

Microsoft added a great and simple mixer that shows the volume and a mute button for all applications that can use sound.

Simply pressing the mute on each twice will quickly figure out what application is generating sound, with the added ability to alter the volume.

This function works both when you are on the desktop, as well as when you are inside a game. You can even record you controlling any program to a small avi, but that is not actually helpful information for the answer to this question. :P

Comment: I figured it out, it was steam